# Typescript definitions for namespaced classes

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm attempting to write typescript defs for a javascript library I wrote. The library looks something like:

```
!function() {
  var mylib = {};

  mylib.Fruit = function() {
    // ...
  };
  mylib.Fruit.SOME_STATIC_PROP = 1;

}();
```

The source is comprised of multiple files that are concatenated -- for this minimal example, there's one file with the first two lines, one with `Fruit`, the other with the last line.

fruit.d.ts:

```
declare module mylib {
  class Fruit {
    static SOME_STATIC_PROP: number;
  }
}
```

In fruit.js (which again is just the middle part of the code pasted above), Intellisense complains:

> Type '() => any' is not assignable to type 'typeof Fruit'. Property 'SOME_STATIC_PROP' is missing in type '() => any'.

**Edit**
In my concatenated file (e.g. what's pasted above), I don't get that message.

If I change fruit.js to something like

```
function Fruit() { ... }
```

without the `mylib` namespace, there's no error either.

Is there a way to avoid this error in my individual "class" files, or should I just ignore them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In fruit.js (which again is just the middle part of the code pasted above), Intellisense complains

Because this is JavaScript, The error `Type '() => any' is not assignable to type 'typeof Fruit'. Property 'SOME_STATIC_PROP' is missing in type '() => any'.` Is based on the *inferred* type of the variable.

## Solutions:

Either:

- Convert the `.js` file to `.ts` so you can use *type annotations* and *type assertions* to massage the types as you like
- Ignore the error is the .js file and move on till you get the time to convert to `.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you need to update your function declaration to be like this:

```
!function() {
  var mylib = {};

  mylib.Fruit = function():Fruit {
    // ...
  };
  mylib.Fruit.SOME_STATIC_PROP = 1;

}();
```

You aren't telling the compiler what the function returns, so it assumes it's an 'any' and any doesn't have a property SOME_STATIC_PROP, but a Fruit type does have that property.

Tell the compiler the exact type that the function returns and it should be happy.

Comment: Not sure I follow -- `:Fruit` is not valid javascript (but is valid TS). But, see the edit I just made -- I don't have this error in the concatenated file, just in the individual class files.